# How to display the count of a filtered array of objects

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of objects which represent few Sections. Each Section contains a number of items. I managed to filter all sections to display the wanted items in my `UITableView` but I can't manage to get the right count of items from my sections. Every time after I filter the array I get the original count of items.
My console is saying: `Number of items in each section: [9, 6]` but in reality in my `UITableView` are only [6, 5]. How can I reflect the right amount of items to use my array forward ?
Here is my code:

```
// MARK : MODEL
class ChecklistItemSection{

    var name: String // name of the section
    var checklistItems: [ChecklistItem] // all items from Checklist

    init(named: String, checklistItems: [ChecklistItem]) {

        self.name = named
        self.checklistItems = checklistItems
    }

    class func checklistItemSections() -> [ChecklistItemSection] {

        var allSections = [vehicleCheck(), viewingScreen(), batteryUnitAndFridge()]

        for (index, section) in allSections.enumerated() {
            if(section.checklistItems.count < 1) {
                allSections.remove(at: index)
            }
        }
        return allSections
    }

    // Private methods
    private class func vehicleCheck() -> ChecklistItemSection {

        var checklistItems = [ChecklistItem]()

        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 109, lineID: 3, poolID: 10, descript: "Tyres - Wear/Damage/Bulges/Cuts/Flat tyres", showVehicle: false, showTrailer: true, highlight: false, pg9: false, imagesPath: [])!)
        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 109, lineID: 4, poolID: 22, descript: "Vehicle and trailer coupling: undamaged and safety locking device working", showVehicle: true, showTrailer: false, highlight: true, pg9: true, imagesPath: [])!)
        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 109, lineID: 7, poolID: 20, descript: "Exhaust - Condition/Emission (Excess smoke)", showVehicle: true, showTrailer: false, highlight: false, pg9: false, imagesPath: [])!)
        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 109, lineID: 3, poolID: 10, descript: "Tyres - Wear/Damage/Bulges/Cuts/Flat tyres", showVehicle: true, showTrailer: false, highlight: false, pg9: false, imagesPath: [])!)
        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 109, lineID: 4, poolID: 22, descript: "Vehicle and trailer coupling: undamaged and safety locking device working", showVehicle: true, showTrailer: true, highlight: true, pg9: true, imagesPath: [])!)
        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 109, lineID: 7, poolID: 20, descript: "Exhaust - Condition/Emission (Excess smoke)", showVehicle: false, showTrailer: true, highlight: false, pg9: false, imagesPath: [])!)
        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 109, lineID: 3, poolID: 10, descript: "Tyres - Wear/Damage/Bulges/Cuts/Flat tyres", showVehicle: false, showTrailer: true, highlight: false, pg9: false, imagesPath: [])!)
        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 109, lineID: 4, poolID: 22, descript: "Vehicle and trailer coupling: undamaged and safety locking device working", showVehicle: true, showTrailer: true, highlight: true, pg9: true, imagesPath: [])!)
        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 109, lineID: 7, poolID: 20, descript: "Exhaust - Condition/Emission (Excess smoke)", showVehicle: false, showTrailer: true, highlight: false, pg9: false, imagesPath: [])!)

        return ChecklistItemSection(named: "Section 1", checklistItems: checklistItems)
    }

    private class func viewingScreen() -> ChecklistItemSection {

        var checklistItems = [ChecklistItem]()

        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 38, lineID: 28, poolID: 16, descript: "Windscreen Wipers & Washers are they effective?", showVehicle: true, showTrailer: false, highlight: false, pg9: false, imagesPath: [])!)

        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 38, lineID: 28, poolID: 16, descript: "Water Level - In cab indicator", showVehicle: true, showTrailer: false, highlight: false, pg9: false, imagesPath: [])!)

        return ChecklistItemSection(named: "Section 2", checklistItems: checklistItems)
    }

    private class func batteryUnitAndFridge() -> ChecklistItemSection {

        var checklistItems = [ChecklistItem]()

        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 38, lineID: 31, poolID: 38, descript: "Battery is held securely in place by the correct means (not cables)", showVehicle: true, showTrailer: true, highlight: false, pg9: true, imagesPath: [])!)
        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 38, lineID: 32, poolID: 39, descript: "Battery cables and pins secure", showVehicle: true, showTrailer: true, highlight: false, pg9: false, imagesPath: [])!)
        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 38, lineID: 33, poolID: 40, descript: "Battery is not leaking", showVehicle: true, showTrailer: true, highlight: false, pg9: false, imagesPath: [])!)
        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 38, lineID: 34, poolID: 38, descript: "Battery is held securely in place by the correct means (not cables)", showVehicle: true, showTrailer: true, highlight: false, pg9: true, imagesPath: [])!)
        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 38, lineID: 35, poolID: 39, descript: "Battery cables and pins secure", showVehicle: false, showTrailer: true, highlight: false, pg9: false, imagesPath: [])!)
        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 38, lineID: 35, poolID: 39, descript: "Battery is not leaking", showVehicle: true, showTrailer: false, highlight: false, pg9: false, imagesPath: [])!)

        return ChecklistItemSection(named: "Section 3", checklistItems: checklistItems)
    }
}

class ChecklistItem {

    var showVehicle: Bool
    var showTrailer: Bool
}

// MARK: VC

class ChecklistVC: UIViewController {

    lazy var checklistItem: [ChecklistItemSection] = { return ChecklistItemSection.checklistItemSections() }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        filterQuestions()
    }

    func filterQuestions() {

        // Show only the questions available for Trailer
        if vehicleRegistrationNumber.isBlank {

            checklistItem.forEach {
                $0.checklistItems.forEach {
                    if $0.showVehicle {
                        $0.showVehicle = false
                    }
                }
            }

            checklistItem = checklistItem.filter { $0.checklistItems.filter { $0.showTrailer && !$0.showVehicle }.count != 0 }.filter {$0.checklistItems.count > 0}
        }

        print("Number of items in each section: \(checklistItem.map {$0.checklistItems.count})") // I get [9, 6] every time. But it should display [6, 5] reflecting the items after filtering.
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading this !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, `filter` doesn't actually remove the items. It just returns a new array with some items removed. So when you are doing a nested filter like this:

```
checklistItem.filter { $0.checklistItems.filter { ... }.count != 0 }
```

It will return `checklistItem` but with some elements removed, and you assign this result to `checklistItem`, hence changing it. But note that the inner arrays of `checklistItem` (i.e. `checkListItems`) are not changed!

The inner `filter` only returns a new array (, and doesn't actually modify the array itself) as well.

I suggest you to `forEach` thing in `checklistItem`, `removeAll` that satisfy the criteria, then remove all of the `checklistItems` that are empty by using another `removeAll`:

```
checklistItem.forEach { $0.checklistItems.removeAll { !$0.showTrailer || $0.showVehicle } }
checklistItem.removeAll { $0.count == 0 }
```

You don't need the extra filter at the end.

Comment: I can't use the second `removeAll` because I get the error `Cannot convert value of type '()' to closure result type 'Bool'`.
If I use `checklistItem.removeAll {$0.checklistItems.filter{!$0.showVehicle && $0.showTrailer}.count != 0}` then I don't get any error but is not working the remove.
If I use `checklistItem.removeAll {$0.checklistItems.removeAll{!$0.showVehicle && $0.showTrailer}}` I get that error.

Comment: I tried your solution but for some reasons after filtering I get every time the same count.
Here is a printscreen: https://imgur.com/a/KwFACXd

Comment: @Flo You've got the wrong condition. It should be `!$0.showTrailer || $0.showVehicle`. With "||". `NOT (showTrailer AND NOT showVehicle)` expands to `NOT showTrailer OR showVehicle` because of DeMorgan's laws.